# Include or Extend relation for "Show chat window", "Receive message" and "Send message" in IM use case diagram?

Tags: uml, messenger

I have a simple usecase diagram of an Instant Messenger, this is a part of it
[image]

1. If user want to Send message, chat window will be showed, so it is "include" or "extend"?
2. If user receiver message, chat will be show before user read the message, so is it "include"?

Comment: Read chapter "Use Case Relationships Compared" in [uml-diagrams.org: UML Use Case Include](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/use-case-include.html). BTW: some of your use case bubbles (Messaging, Receive message,..) don't look like use cases where the user actor plays an active role. They look more like activities performed by the system in order to support a master use case scenario where the user acts only as a stakeholder

Comment: If youe use case diagrams resemble a spiders web then your design is likely broken (forgot where I read it, but it's true).

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of discussion, and a lot of different opinions on what exactly the difference is between include and extend.
One of the best articles about this subject is this one: [Excavating the extension use case](http://www.batimes.com/articles/excavating-the-extension-use-case.html)

In a team with a lot of analysts it is often advisable to take a pragmatic approach and use only includes. That avoids a lot of confusion and discussion. I'm still waiting for the case that cannot be solved by includes alone.

Comment: Interesting.  Not sure I get it.  So, suppose you have a "Pay Bill" use case at Kroger's.  How would you handle "Process Coupon" or "Process Discount Card" with an include?

Comment: @BobRodes Yes I would. I know that a some authors interpret "include" as something that **always** is executed and extend as something that is only **sometimes** executed, but I think that is mostly personal interpretation of these authors. I don't find a direct indication of that in the UML specs (see UML 2.5 Beta2 p. 670 and folowing pages). In my UML courses I usually illustrate extend with a use case called "Log security Audit". That is one of the only good examples I could find as the base use case should not know about this security audit.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking how you would, not whether you would.  Perhaps you can explain?

Comment: I believe this is a "direct indication" from the spec: "Note, however, that the extended use case is defined independently of the extending use case and is meaningful independently of the extending use case. On the other hand, the extending use case typically defines behavior that may not necessarily be meaningful by itself. Instead, the extending use case defines a set of modular behavior increments that augment an execution of the extended use case under specific conditions."  If the conditions are met, it executes, otherwise not.  Ergo conditional execution.  (Superstructure 2.4.1, p. 601)

Comment: Also: "If the condition of the extension is true at the time the first extension point is reached during the execution of the extended use case, then all of the appropriate behavior fragments of the extending use case will also be executed. If the condition is false, the extension does not occur."  Again, conditional execution.  (ibid. p. 602)  I would call these direct indications of the optional nature of an extension in the UML spec.  Also, the spec states "the included use case is not optional, and is always required for the including use case to execute correctly (ibid., p 605)

Comment: So, I guess I don't agree with your comment that the interpretation you describe doesn't have a basis in the spec.  Looking at the 2.5 beta, I find this on extensions: "If the condition of the Extend is missing or evaluates to true at the time the first ExtensionPoint is reached during the execution of the extended UseCase, then all of the appropriate behavior fragments of the extending UseCase will also be executed. If the condition is false, this does not happen."

Comment: Also, this on inclusions: "The included UseCase must be available for the behavior of the including UseCase to be completely described."  They might as well have said "This spec intentionally left vague."  :)

Answer (score 0):

Include and extend can both be used to express the same thing, but the semantics are somewhat different and since you're using EA there's a simple way of choosing: extension points.

A use case extension point is very roughly similar to a template parameter in source code: it indicates that in the more generic entity you have decided beforehand to make it extensible in a certain way. There is no equivalent semantics for the include relationship.

If a use case has extension points, EA lets you choose which point an extending use case extends. If you find yourself struggling to define extension points or choosing between them, it's probably a better idea to use include relationships instead. If you don't define any extension points at all, I see no reason to use extend in the first place.

So in your example, "Send message" and "Receive message" should both include "Show chat window". You've drawn the connectors the wrong way around, though.

Comment: I agree with @xmojmr that there are several issues with this set of use cases, which makes it harder to pick the right relationships. However, this answer deals only with the include/extend question.